# Write shell script in Windows Xp

Tags: shell, build, cygwin

I have to write the shell script, which will run on cygwin and build my projects. I am using Windows - Xp. How can I do that?

( I am newbie for shell script)

Comment: So you can learn how to write shell script.

Comment: A good beginner's tutorial: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/

Comment: Thanks Tom, that helped me so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you'll need to get some scripting knowledges. You can start [with this tutorial](http://linux.org.mt/article/terminal).

For a hello world shell script:

1. Open Cygwin
2. Create a Hello World script: `echo "echo Hello World!" > hello.sh`. It is a file with the only line `echo Hello World!`
3. Run the script `./hello.sh`

`man` is your friend!

Comment: you forgot about the shebang as well as making the script executable using `chmod`

Comment: @Fredrik You're absolutely right. It worked for me in Cygwin like this, however. Except for the double-quotes, they've got to be single ones.

Comment: It runs exactly as mentioned by Xavi for me, not even single quotes required 

And hence I am able to explore it more

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

well cygwins default shell is `bash`, google that and then get back here on SO with a more specific question...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building your projects from the cygwin command prompt?

Before you start writing a script, you need to know which commands you need to build your project.